# Access React app from other React app on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-habitat

I have a situation where I have written the front-end of my website as micro-services. Every functional section of my website is a react-habitat application bundled with css and html.  I have done this so I can re-use these sections wherever I want on the site.

My problem is however in the checkout area I need to pass the customerId from the login application (on successful response) into the delivery address application so I can bring back the default address. I don't want to create a new application and duplicate the code for login and delivery address applications because I will need to use them elsewhere on the website.

So my question is. How can I pass this customerId from my login application to my delivery address application without a page reload? Is there a way to access a react application method from outside of that react application?

Login click handler:

```
clickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let payload = {"email":this.props.email, "password":this.props.password};

        AuthenticationApp.login(payload).then((response) => {
            if (this.props.referrer === "checkout") {
                $("#checkout_login-register-tab").addClass("done");
                $("#checkout_login-delivery-tab").removeClass("todo");

                // Temporary hack to reload page until we can pass new user session into delivery/billing react app from here.
                location.reload();
            }
            this.props.updateParentState({isLoggedIn: true});
        })
        .catch(function(response){
            console.log("res2 - catch", response)
        });
    }
```

I have forced a page reload here so the delivery address application re-renders and picks up customerId from the service. I need a way to re-render the delivery application at this stage (from this separate application), either by accessing a function somehow or forcing the application to reset? Is this possible or is there a workaround other than a page reload?

Comment: Your delivery address application is a non-react app and your login is a react component and you need to pass some data from your login app to delivery app, am I right?

Comment: No the delivery app is a separate react application. So I need to pass a variable from 1 to the other by accessing a function in the delivery react application from the login application so I can then update the state, and thus gain control of this app.

Comment: If you want to use some data ( in your case customer id ) after you login you need to set session data, either in localstorage or cookie, and then you can access that data anywhere in your delivery application. Can you add some code for your login and delivery app?

Comment: My issue is not storing the data here - it is gaining control of this data in the delivery application without reloading the page. On page reload I can access the customerId as it gets picked up from the service - but to prevent page reload I need to somehow either reset the delivery application on the page so it hits the services again, or access a function in the delivery application  to update state (forcing re-render).

Comment: Changed tag 'habitat' to 'react-habitat'. Part of effort to split up ambiguous tag 'habitat'

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
loadDeliveryApp(data) {
   ReactDOM.render(<DeliveryApp data={data} />, document.getElementById('delivery-app'))
   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById("login-app"))
}

clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // your login stuff

  loadDeliveryApp(data)
}
```

Here is the working demo.

https://codepen.io/madhurgarg71/pen/dzgxMd

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original creator of React Habitat.. all your applications can talk to each other via either a flux observer or something like redux.

I suggest [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) for react habitat normally as the individual stores keep it light weight instead of one BIG store in redux where you might have dead code in a habitat situation.

You will need to create one common store that both your applications import so that if one changes it, the other will get the update. I can put a demo together later if that helps.

Comment: A code example of this would be useful. Not used Flux before.